# selenium-webdriver won't execute next step after opening browser

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automated-tests, cucumberjs

I've been trying to automate our web testing by using `cucumber-js` and `selenium-webdriver`. I wrote an example of simple web navigation, but I always get blank page and the runner stopped doing anything. Here is the code piece:

```
// my_project/features/step_definitions/SomeTest.js

const { Given, When, Then } = require('cucumber')
const { assert, expect } = require('chai')
const webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver')

var browser = new webdriver.Builder()
.forBrowser('chrome')
.build();

Given("I'm on landing page", function() {
    browser.get('https://www.google.com')
});
```

Here is my SomeTest.feature:

```
// my_project/features/SomeTest.feature

    Feature: Some Test

    As a user I want to search a keyword on Google

    @first
    Scenario: Search a word
    Given I'm on landing page
    When I typed in "test"
    Then I should get redirected search result page
```

After I run the test with `./node_modules/.bin/cucumber-js`
what I get is always blank page either on chrome or firefox.

[image: This is what I got after running the test]

*Does anybody experiencing the same issue? Any idea how to solve or at least debug this?*

P.S. I'm using `Chrome 65`, and `chromedriver 2.40.565383`, `Firefox 56` and `geckodriver 0.21.0` running on 64-bit ubuntu 14.04

Comment: What does `"I'm on landing page"` relate to? Afaik there should be some code associated with that. If that condition is not met, the inner code won't execute

Comment: Yes. It's on the gherkin feature file, I already defined. The webdriver seems only spawn the browser and does not proceed with the code

Comment: I want to improve my answer. Can you post those files as well? Edit the question and add them there

Comment: I see, I will update it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is:

```
Given("I'm on landing page", function() {
    return browser.get('https://www.google.com')
});
```

Or

```
Given("I'm on landing page", function(callback) {
    browser.get('https://www.google.com');
    callback();
});
```

The return and callback will signify to the function (and therefore cucumber) that the step has finished executing.

In some cases you may want to wait for everything inside to execute in order, which is where `async` and `await` comes into it (readily available on Node 10.3.0+):

```
Given("I'm on landing page", async function() {
    return await browser.get('https://www.google.com');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As can be seen in the very [example of cucumber-js](http://cucumber.github.io/cucumber-js/), you need:

- a feature file <- you don't have this or is not properly set up
- step definition <- you don't have this or is not properly set up
- the code that uses the step definition <- this you have

Until you fix this, this code won't execute indeed:

```
Given("I'm on landing page", function() {
    browser.get('https://www.google.com')
    browser.quit()
});
```

Comment: No, I already got all of them and It still happen. Thank you for answering :)

Comment: What Kyle wants to say is downvote this answer and upvote his

Answer (score -2):

Actually I just figured it out,

I need to add "callback" inside the function parameter, like so:

```
Given("I'm on landing page", function() {
    browser.get('https://www.google.com')
    browser.quit()
});
```

To this,

```
Given("I'm on landing page", function(callback) {
    browser.get('https://www.google.com')
    browser.quit()
});
```

Comment: this solve the blank page problem, however another problem appear because of this